# C# XAML MVVM Treeview control Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I can not display the item list.
What am I doing wrong?

XAML(View):

```
<Grid.DataContext>
     <vm:MainViewModel />
</Grid.DataContext>

<Grid.Resources>
     <DataTemplate x:Key="Remedy">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titulo}" />
     </DataTemplate>

     <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Laboratorio"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Remedy}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titulo}" />
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Root"
                               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Laboratorio}"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titulo}" />
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

</Grid.Resources>

<TreeView x:Name="dirR"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Arbol}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Root}">
</TreeView>
```

C# (ViewModel):

```
class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private TreeItem _arbol = new TreeItem("Remedys");
   public TreeItem Arbol
   {
      set 
      { 
         _arbol = value; 
         OnPropertyChanged("Arbol"); 
      }
         get { return _arbol; }
   }

   public MainViewModel()
   {
       //Populate Arbol
       ...
    }
}
```

C# (Model):

```
public class TreeItem:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _titulo;
    private ObservableCollection<TreeItem> _items;
    public String Titulo
    {
        get { return _titulo; }
        set 
        {
            _titulo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Titulo");
        } 
    }
    public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set 
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
    public TreeItem(String __titulo) 
    {
        Titulo = __titulo;
    }
```

C# (MainWindow v1):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}
```

C# (MainWindow v2) This version works ok but I do not like it because there is code dependency between View and Viewmodel

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
    dirR.Items.Add(vm.Arbol);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question after you have read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: You have to in your MainWindow set DataContext = new MainViewModel();

Comment: Is this question really about TreeView binding? Or is it about decoupling code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only bind a value to `ItemsSource` which implements `IEnumerable`. Generally spoken you have to bind a **collection** to `ItemsSource`.

Change your `MainViewModel` to

```
class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private ObservableCollection<TreeItem> _arbol = 
       new ObservableCollection<TreeItem>( 
           new List<TreeItem>
           { 
               new TreeItem("Remedys") 
           } );
   public ObservableCollection<TreeItem> Arbol
   {
      set 
      { 
         _arbol = value; 
         OnPropertyChanged("Arbol"); 
      }
         get { return _arbol; }
   }

   public MainViewModel()
   {
       //Populate Arbol
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set DataContext in MainWindow code:

From XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

From code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

  DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```